# <input type="file" /> file format validation not working in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, google-chrome

I am validating my form with Jquery validator "http://jqueryvalidation.org/".
I am getting an issue when I am validating the "`<input type="file" />`" field, its "`required: true,`" validation is working and when I accept the wrong file type it throws error. But in "**IE and Chrome**" if I select the correct file format, still it gives the error, though its working correctly in Firefox.

Created the Fiddle too... This is how it is exactly working for me:
**http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/v6x8P/**

**If you check in Chrome & IE it will give the issue, but if you check in Firefox it will work and will give the aert for "Submitted"!

[image]

Please find the code mentioned below:-

**Jquery**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>

<script>

    $().ready(function () {

        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#deploymentUploadForm").validate({

            rules:{
                File: {
                    required: true,
                    accept: "zip"
                }
            },

            messages:{
                File: {
                    required: "This field is mandatory!",
                    accept: "Accepts only zip file!"
                }
            }  

        });

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="~/Deployment/FileUpload" name="deploymentUploadForm" id="deploymentUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <h1>Deployment</h1>
   <p>
       <input type="file" name="File" accept="application/zip">
   </p>
   <div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
     <p>
       <input type="submit" id="getDeploymentList" value="Upload" class="active" >  
     </p>
   </div>
</form>
```

**OnSubmit JQUERY**

```
$("#getDeploymentList").click(function () {
    if ($("#deploymentUploadForm").valid()) {

        $("#deploymentUploadForm").submit();
        $('#stepSummary').empty();
        $.loader({
            className: "blue-with-image",
            content: 'Please wait...Your request is being processed!'
        });

    };
});
```

Please let me know if you need any other info.

Thanks in adavace!

Comment: @TusharGupta: no, they are the same, as is even $(function)...

Comment: @dandavis oh sorry i got it

Comment: You fiddle works fine in Chrome 29 on OS X. Which IE are you testing? As the validation uses the HTML5 file API, it will fail in IE9 and below, [see](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

Comment: Strange! I'am using the same "Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m" and IE 10, but still only the file type validation not working! I am including the screenshot too in my Question!

Comment: Note that the documentation claims that [`accept` uses MIME types](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method), while `zip` is not a MIME type. (That said, on my Mac Chrome just filters the Select File dialog for `.zip` file name extensions, and disables ZIP files that don't have that extension, when using your Fiddle. That's not very nice, but might suit your needs.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with(HTML):

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" accept=".zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed" />
```

jQuery( validation )

```
accept: "application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"
```

and with jQuery plugin( idea ):

```
(function( $ )
{
    $.fn.acceptFileType=function( types )
    {
        if ( types == undefined )
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            types = types.split(",")
        }
        this.each(function(){
            $( this ).bind("change",function()
            {
                if( !$.inArray( $( this ).val().replace(/([\d\w.]+)(\.[a-z0-9]+)/i,'\2') , types ) )
                {
                    $( this ).val('');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
$( ":file" ).acceptFileType(".zip");
```

And if you have a PHP, see this repo

> https://github.com/erlandsen/upload

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the "accept: 'application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"' and it worked.. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the fiddle to work by changing your accept rule from zip to the following:

```
accept: "application/zip,application/octet-stream,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"
```

It looks like Firefox uses a different MIME type for the zip files than IE or Chrome.  This uses a broader list of MIME types for zip files.  You will need to decide if it is too broad for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the "accept: 'application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"' and it worked.. Thanks a ton!